# Golang Sprintf formatting a string and using it multiple times

Tags: go, printf

I try to generate a sql query using `Sprintf()` where I have to use the same variable two times

```
myStr := "test"
str := Sprintf("SELECT ... WHERE a = '%#[1]s' or b = '%#[1]s'", myStr)
fmt.Println(str)
```

This snippets outputs the expected string

```
SELECT ... WHERE a = 'test' or b = 'test'
```

but `go vet` says:

```
unrecognized printf flag for verb 's': '#' (vet)
```

And I am puzzled why. Switching the printf verb to `v` satisfies `go vet` but adds `"` around my string. And I honestly doesn't see a mistake in using `%#[1]s`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you use `%#[1]s` instead of `%[1]s`?

Comment: What do you expect the flag `#` to do with strings `s`? What in the package documentation makes you believe # modifies the verb `s`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `printf` to construct queries is a bad idea, it opens you up to SQL injection.

See named parameters in the [sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Named) package.

Comment: great tip, but doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 4):

There is no # Sprintf flag for a string verb (the flag # is e.g. adding 0x for hex values: %#x). So remove it to make your go vet troubles disappear:

```
myStr := "test"
str := Sprintf("SELECT ... WHERE a = '%[1]s' or b = '%[1]s'", myStr)
fmt.Println(str)
```

But: If any part of your constructed query (myStr) comes from external input (i.e. user input), you really should follow Hein's advise and use named parameters.